# Date function in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

What is the difference between next two query in `Oracle DB` (`11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0`):

```
SELECT DATE '2018-02-01'  FROM DUAL;
```

and

```
SELECT DATE('2018-02-01') FROM DUAL;
```

Where the `first one work fine`, but the `next one I get next error`:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Thanks
BR

Comment: There is no function `date()` - you probably want `to_date()`

Comment: The same difference that between `N'foo'` and `N('foo')`. Not everything that has parenthesis is a function call, but all function calls need parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1):

> You can specify a `DATE` value as a string literal, or you can convert a
>   character or numeric value to a date value with the `TO_DATE` function.
>   `DATE` literals are the only case in which Oracle Database accepts a
>   `TO_DATE` expression in place of a string literal.
>   To specify a `DATE` value as a literal, you must use the Gregorian
>   calendar. You can specify an ANSI literal, as shown in this example:
>
> ```
> DATE '1998-12-25'
> ```
>
> The ANSI date literal contains no time portion, and must be specified
>   in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`. Alternatively you can specify an Oracle
>   date value, as in the following example:
>
> ```
> TO_DATE('98-DEC-25 17:30','YY-MON-DD HH24:MI')
> ```

Please notice that, according to Wernfried Domscheit, using only 2 digits for years is not a great idea. If you want to use a `to_date`, you would better use a 4-digit format:

```
TO_DATE('1998-DEC-25 17:30','YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI')
```

Comment: Using only 2 digits for year is not very smart. Your example is the best proof - did you like to get `2098-12-25` rather than `1998-12-25`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: It's from Oracle documentation :). Edited to clarify, thanks